# How to autoplay youtube videos in ChromiumWebBrowser v71.0.2?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I tried the lower ChromiumWebBrowser version and autoplay youtube works normally, now I upgrade ChromiumWebBrowser v71.0.2 and it doesn't autoplay the video anymore, which solution can I fix this?

Comment: Chrome changed the auto play policy,  you can manually override the default using https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/db306a64c93018ebec0ce9fe0da0484e52efbf61#diff-8504643e16a7bcd2d9428f463a767ff9

Comment: You should read https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes confirm that you've read it before asking any further questions